# Is Spring Batch JpaItemWriter stateful?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, rollback, spring-retry

Is Spring Batch `JpaItemWriter` stateful? i mean if through writing process a failure happened does it know where is that left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The `JpaItemWriter` maintains no state.  State for a failure is handled at the reader side of the step in most cases (since it's the one providing the items to be written).